# VisualSVN Server URL to include my domain name

Tags: svn, dns, visualsvn-server

After setting up a VisualSVN Server for source control on my web server. I connect to it via a URL such as: http://123.456.789.000/svn/.

While this works fine, I wonder if I could make the URL incorporate my domain name eg: `http://www.example.com/svn/`.

The domain name also points to same server as my website is also hosted on it. Any tips for this?

Comment: I'm guessing that's a fake (invalid) IP

Comment: Yes thats correct, just for illustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the **VisualSVN Manager** management console, go to the **Properties** of your server. On the **Network** tab you can change the server name and port number. Just make sure your domain name points to that server's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Your [DNS (Domain Name System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/dns-top) is responsible for associating a domain name with an IP address of a computer. Therefore, when you want to point an IP address to a server computer, you need to make changes on your DNS.

However, when you want to change the URL used in VisualSVN Server in cases when e.g. you copy the URL to clipboard you can follow these steps:

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Click **Action | Properties**.
3. Click the **Network** tab.
4. Change the **Server name** and click **Apply**.

[image]